# Order Allocation Ship Complete

Tags: sql, arrays

I have 250 locations with 350 thousand items in a table called the item location map, the primary key of this table is item_id, location, on_hand_count.

> **Location_ID** | **item_id** | **on_hand_count**

Currently, we receive orders and will identify the closest locations and attempt to allocate orders to those locations after a query of the above table to identify what location has stock.

However, in the event we receive TWO items on the same order, they are being split between multiple locations. We need to identify how to write a query that will quickly identify locations that have at least X number of units (we'll say 3 for now) of each SKU in the SAME location.

The goal will send orders that we think can ship complete from a single location that would have all of the products in the order.

Comment: Please post DDL,DML Of the tables involved and dont post images.Having this info helps others to quickly repro your issue and asnwer better.Below is some sample which might help you understand.  

**--sample data**  
`create table #t1
(
id int
)

insert into #t1
values
(1),
(2),
(1)
`    
**my current query/what i have tried:**   
`select id,count(*) as cnt from
#t1
group by id`  

**my current result:**  
`id cnt
1  2
2  1`

**my expected result:**
`id cnt
1  2
2  1
1  2`

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate your table over location, and check that every SKU has an on hand count of at least 3:

```
SELECT
    Location_ID
FROM items
WHERE item_id IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY
    Location_ID
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN on_hand_count < 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 AND
    COUNT(DISTINCT item_id) = 3
```

The first term of the `HAVING` clause ensures that every item has the required stock, and the second term ensures that every item is present at a given location.

Comment: This will give me a location where the items are present with that count, but it won't tell me when 3 unique items are all present at that same store.

Comment: I updated my query, just add one more term to the `HAVING` clause.  Sorry, but your requirements were not entirely clear.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic representation of what you're trying to do - mostly completed as SQL.  This takes the order entered as a bind variable (:ORDER), finds all items on that list - joins those items to all locations that contain those items, groups on the location to find the number of items that match with sufficient quantity matching to the order, and then filters it down to locations that contain matches for every line on the order.

Note that this query will not work properly if you allow an item to be repeated on multiple sales order detail lines.  If that is the case, you'll need to write an aggregate subquery to SUM those quantities on each line so you are looking for the total amount of each item needed.

```
select INVENTORY.LOCATION, count (INVENTORY.ITEMS)
from INVENTORY
inner join 
(select SO_DETAIL.ITEMS from SO_DETAIL where SO_DETAIL.ORDER_NUM = (:ORDER) ) ORDERITEMS
    on INVENTORY.ITEMS = ORDERITEMS.ITEMS 
    and INVENTORY.QUANTITY >= ORDERITEMS.QUANTITY
group by INVENTORY.LOCATION
having count(INVENTORY.ITEMS) = (select count(SO_DETAIL.ITEMS) from SO_DETAIL where SO_DETAIL.ORDER_NUM = (:ORDER) )
```